# скрипт валидации email

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток всем, есть скрипт проверки **email**, который сравнивает подтверждающий **email**, если вводить все последовательно то работает. Но если ввести все данные и изменить введенный **email**, то подтверждающий **email** не срабатывает, как автоматически вызывать обработчик данных?

**вводимый email**

```
$("#email").change(function(){
        email = $("#email").val();
        //#^[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+\.([a-z0-9]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$#
        var expEmail = /^[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+\.([a-z0-9]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/;
        var resEmail = email.search(expEmail);
        if(resEmail == -1){
            $("#email").next().hide().text("неверный формат E-mail").css("color","red").fadeIn(400);
            $("#email").removeClass().addClass("inputRed");

        }else{                  
                    $("#email").removeClass().addClass("inputGreen");
                    $("#email").next().text("");
                }   
});

**
```

**проверка совпадения email**

```
        $("#email2").change(function(){
         if(email2 != email){
            $("#email2").next().hide().text("Е-mail не совпадает").css("color","red").fadeIn(400);
            $("#email2").removeClass().addClass("inputRed");

        }else{
            $("#email2").removeClass().addClass("inputGreen");
            $("#email2").next().text("");
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Добавьте в проверку первого email условие, которое смотрит если email2 не пустой, то выполнить функцию, которая сравнивает оба емейла

Comment: ^ или проверяйте при submit

Comment: при submit проверяется, нужно что бы проверка была при изменении вводимого емейл

Comment: вам в первом комменте про такой вариант и написали

Comment: оффтоп: за такие проверки надо руки отрывать. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: за какие проверки?

Comment: за `expEmail`. Половина реальных существующих адресов её не пройдёт.

Comment: {1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6} расширить значения и все пройдут допустим до {1,60}\.)?[a-z]{2,60} и все пройдут

Comment: `test+tag@gmail.com` не пройдёт. `тест@яндекс.рф` не пройдёт.

Comment: при попытки зарегистрировать test+tag@gmail.com (на самом сайте gmail.com) мне выдало Please use only letters (a-z), numbers, and periods, а по поводу тест@яндекс.рф не проблема добавить кириллицу в правило

Comment: Это не значит, что такого адреса не существует. https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html А добавить ещё десяток языков (арабский, тайский и т.п.) тоже не проблема?

Comment: не проблема подключить библиотеку с языками, а что касается почти с плюсом test+gg@gmail.com я таких в обороте не видел, да и много сайтов вообще фильтруют по самой почте, так что тут уже дело индивидуальное

Comment: Конечно не видел. Пользователи просто не могут использовать такой адрес в вашем интерфейсе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#email2").change(function(){
let email = $("#email").val();
let email2 = $("#email2").val();
     if(email2 != email){
        $("#email2").next().hide().text("Е-mail не совпадает").css("color","red").fadeIn(400);
        $("#email2").removeClass().addClass("inputRed");

    }else{
        $("#email2").removeClass().addClass("inputGreen");
        $("#email2").next().text("");
    }   
});
```

Comment: почти оно, теперь не срабатывает событие правильной валидации емейл, а именно вводимый емейл не подсвечивается зеленым

Comment: не пойму что не подсвечивается??? У меня все подсвечивается)

Comment: все уже сделал путем придания условий, ведь в первоначальном виде если использовать хаотичный набор данных то не все условия срабатывали